# Length of an audio file (e.g .wav) using RubyAudio

Tags: ruby

How can I determine the length (in ms) of an audio file (e.g .wav) using RubyAudio

```
s = RubyAudio::Sound.open("1.wav")
```

Comment: Why in ms? Such a great accuracy. I didn't know that audio files had length information to that accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the SongInfo by:

```
songInfo = s.info
```

And then the song info contains the sample rate and the number of frames which you can use to calculate the duration of the sound file:

```
duration = songInfo.frames / songInfo.samplerate
```

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory look at the docs, it looks like you can't do that with RubyAudio.

Have you tried looking at [`ruby-mp3info`](http://ruby-mp3info.rubyforge.org/)? I don't know if it's still actively developed, nor if it works for multiple audio formats, but it claims to be able to give you the duration of an mp3.

An alternate way would be to do an estimate based on the bitrate and the file length.

Comment: Yeah, that's my guess based on the C source too. I thought about answering with an estimation based on the bitrate and the file length, but I wasn't sure about it. Is WAV supported by ruby-mp3info? (I didn't read the docs thoroughly, I confess! But from a quick look at it, it doesn't seem like it does)

Answer (score 0):

RubyAudio doesn't appear to have been updated in six years and its documentation is sparse. If you're able I'd recommend using [rtaglib](http://rtaglib.rubyforge.org/) instead.

However, if you're married to RubyAudio it looks like you can get both a frame count (`Audio::Soundfile#frames`) and a sample (frame) rate (`Audio::Soundfile#samplerate`). Knowing this you should be able to divide the number of frames by sample rate to get the length of the file in seconds.